# How to read SoapObject came from service as a collection of list object to ArrayList<Person>?

Tags: android, web-services

I have a service and whenever I call that one I am getting `SoapObject` when convert it into string as:

```
Persons=anyType{firstname=raj; lastname=nag; age=25;};
Persons=anyType{firstname=baa; lastname=rta; age=26;};
Persons=anyType{firstname=har; lastname=kiu; age=27;};
```

so how can I convert above string to `ArrayList<Person>` objects collection?

Thanks,
nag.

Comment: Can you post some piece of code you tried to get this as response?

Comment: i completed the stuff to bind into ArrayList<Person> can you please tell me the way to convert this arraylist objects to TableLayout?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get through this thanks to **SeeSharpWriter**'s tutorial at http://seesharpgears.blogspot.fr/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html